# Outputting JSON Data in Angular Expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

My PHP script returns this JSON data:

```
{
  "userData": {
    "userName": "knows_nothing",
    "userFullName": "Jon Snow",
    "userMoney": "124.01"
  }
}
```

How can I access the variables (userName etc) in my webpage?

eg:

#### JS

```
var app = angular.module('dashboard', []);
app.controller('userDataCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    data = "{query:'userData'}"
    $.post("api/mysql.php", {query:'userData'})
    .then(function (response) {$scope.userData = response.userData;});
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div ng-app="dashboard">
    <div ng-controller="userDataCtrl">
        <h1> Username: {{ userData.userName }} </h1>
        <p> Balance: {{ userData.balance }} </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This has been driving me insane for hours :(

This is what it outputs when I `console.log(response.userData)

```
Object { userName: "knows_nothing", userFullName: "Jon Snow", userMoney: "124.01" }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: And is the data returned as you expect it? You can check this in the Network tab of most developer tools.

Comment: you can see example http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_http_get   you don't have ng-controller="myCtrl" on div. you need to add ng-controller attribute to div.

Comment: @UmutCatal I have tried ng-controller on the same div, and it doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielEdwards I get `userData: Object` and then 'userName: "knows_nothing"` etc..

Comment: Are you getting response?

Comment: @MickeyPatel yeah, see my previous comment.

Comment: This line is weird: `.then(function (response) {$scope.userData = response.userData;})`. The actual data from the response resides in `response.data`.

Comment: Console.log the response and see what it looks like, the code looks OK to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) you should read the response from `response.data`. So, in your case:

```
...
.then(function (response) {$scope.userData = response.data.userData;});
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I also had to change `$.post` to `$http.post`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to declare the $scope.userData variable outside of the then-function

Answer (score 0):

check if your response is array, if array then you need to do something like this,
$scope.userData = response[0].userData.

If still not getting solution please share or response format.Entire response structure.

Comment: I updated my main post, when I console log response.userData I get: `Object { userName: "knows_nothing", userFullName: "Jon Snow", userMoney: "124.01" }`